# Textfield JavaFX com máscara dinamica para valores monetários

Tags: java, javafx

Estou tentando criar um textfield java FX para uma aplicação financeira. Gostaria que esse texfield seguisse o mesmo padrão do campos numericos encontrados em caixas eletronicos bancarios. Por exemplo : no ATM o valor inicial no campo de valor é "0.00". Quando o usuario digita o valor que quer sacar por exemplo, a digitação começa da direita para a esquerda, substituindo os zeros iniciais...Por exemplo, quero sacar $99.90 (usuario digita a tecla 9 tres vezes e tecla 0 uma vez) e acontece isso :

> 0.09 -> 0.99 -> 9.99-> 99.90

Alguem tem uma idéia de como criar esta máscara? Já vi varias respostas em tópicos parecidos mas não consegui adaptar nenhuma para o meu projeto (talvez porque eu seja um iniciante em Java e ainda estou aprendendo sobre a classe String,metodos do textfield,etc.)

Comment: Usa Java 8 ou 9? Pretende usar alguma API de moedas ou só tratar o texto?

Comment: Estou utilizando Java 8 e só quero tratar o texto (até porque não estou familiarizado ainda  com APIS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz uma pequena extensão para o TextField do JavaFX que formata como se fosse um campo monetário. Estou utilizando Double nesta solução mas você pode alterar como te convenha:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 * Simple Currency Field for JavaFX
 * @author Gustavo
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class CurrencyField extends TextField{

    private NumberFormat format;
    private SimpleDoubleProperty amount;

    public CurrencyField(Locale locale) {
        this(locale, 0.00);
    }

    public CurrencyField(Locale locale, Double initialAmount) {
        setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        amount = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "amount", initialAmount);
        format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        setText(format.format(initialAmount));

        // Remove selection when textfield gets focus
        focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                int lenght = getText().length();
                selectRange(lenght, lenght);
                positionCaret(lenght);
            });
        });

        // Listen the text's changes
        textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                formatText(newValue);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the current amount value
     * @return Total amount
     */
    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount.get();
    }

    /**
     * Property getter
     * @return SimpleDoubleProperty
     */
    public SimpleDoubleProperty amountProperty() {
        return this.amount;
    }

    /**
     * Change the current amount value
     * @param newAmount
     */
    public void setAmount(Double newAmount) {
        if(newAmount >= 0.0) {
            amount.set(newAmount);
            formatText(format.format(newAmount));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set Currency format
     * @param locale
     */
    public void setCurrencyFormat(Locale locale) {
        format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        formatText(format.format(getAmount()));
    }

    private void formatText(String text) {
        if(text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
            String plainText = text.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

            while(plainText.length() < 3) {
                plainText = "0" + plainText;
            }

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(plainText);
            builder.insert(plainText.length() - 2, ".");

            Double newValue = Double.parseDouble(builder.toString());
            amount.set(newValue);
            setText(format.format(newValue));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteText(int start, int end) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(getText());
        builder.delete(start, end);
        formatText(builder.toString());
        selectRange(start, start);
    }

}
```

Basicamente ele pega o impute e formata para moeda usando o NumberFormat a partir de um locale. O método `formatText(String)` remove tudo que não é número do texto e coloca um ponto em duas casas decimais, preenchendo com zeros à esquerda caso o número seja pequeno. Abaixo um exemplo de uso:

```
CurrencyField cur = new CurrencyField(new Locale("pt","BR"));

// Usando esta property você pode ver as mudanças no valor do textfield
cur.amountProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                System.out.println(newValue.doubleValue());
            }
        });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Talvez tenha alguns bugs que eu não notei, [qualquer coisa sinalize para ajudar a melhora-lo](https://github.com/gbfragoso/FXcomponents/blob/master/src/application/CurrencyField.java)!

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu estava buscando!Vou estudar este código para aprender mais e ver se precisa de alguma adaptação especifica para o meu projeto. Caso eu faça alguma alteração significativa postarei aqui a titulo  de curiosidade. Gustavo Fragoso muito obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento.

Comment: Surgiu uma dúvida: como eu posso utilizar o objeto CurrencyField a partir de um arquivo FXML ? Testei em um projeto FX sem FXML e funcionou exatamente como eu precisava...

Comment: Pra colocar no FXML é obrigatório um construtor vazio (sem argumentos). Seria 'this(new Locale("pt","BR"), 0.0); Dê uma olhada como eu usei FXML nesse componente: https://github.com/gbfragoso/MaskedTextField

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado